# What are the type elements vulnerabilities?

Tags: pokemon-go

Which type element pokemon is strong/weak against each one?

Water -> Fire?
Plant -> Water?

I think every pokemon has a element type, and every element is stronger against another one.

Comment: Does Go have dual-typed pokemon?

Comment: @Pyritie: Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changed in early 2017; Pokémon Go introduced immunity (basically as double resistance, 0.51x) and modified the Super Effective / Not Very Effective (to 1.4x / 0.71x) as well.

This is nicely displayed, as well as discussed, in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6if11e/mobilefriendly_type_effectiveness_chart_with/).  The image from that thread follows.

[image: Table of effectiveness]

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of elements, so I'm just going to link to [this table](http://pokemondb.net/type) which summarises them all for Pokemon X & Y; I expect the list for Pokemon Go may be slightly different, but I don't think anyone has yet compiled a table for that.

For example, water is super effective against fire, fire is super effective against grass, and grass is super effective against water.

[image: Element table]

And here is an alternative representation of the same information that may be easier to read for some. The center column is the attacking type; it is super effective against the types to its right, and not very effective against the types to its left.

[image: Element chart]

Comment: Could you please add the image to your answer so if the external website goes off this answer is still valid? You can still put the reference, but the answer must contain the basic information

Comment: I can personally confirm that immunities seem to be ignored. I used dig (ground type) against a flying type and it hit but was considered "not very effective".

Comment: Although only the original 15x Pokemon are currently available, newer types like Steel and Fairy are absolutely available. I don't think anyone's really done the research to be able to definitely pin one of the previous type charts to Pokemon GO.

Comment: Actually, this answer has some good work: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/274269/106721

Answer (score 3):

Another representation of types that may come in handy:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### The Table Attack \ Defense Table

- Below shows which Pokemon Attacks are strong
- **Attack** on *Left*, **Defending/Pokemon** Type along the *top*
- **1.25** means they deal **extra damage**, while **0.8** means they deal **less damage**

#### Visual Table as Image

[image]

Here is the solid [reference](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ1daunztOgvOZxO7ABfJPF41-2mqMDzY1Qs_0OWwq8/htmlview?sle=true#) to Google Doc by [TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4se870/pokemon_cp_tier_list/) on reddit, where it was determined by actual game play stats.

Comment: Why there are two identical tables?

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks for the user experience feedback! I see how it was confusing, it needed calrity. Since I think the graphic works for most people I left that and removed the text version to reduce clutter and confusion.