# Which generation does Pokemon Go base its move type effectiveness on?

Tags: pokemon-go

Only generation-I Pokemon are available, however it seems that the types which did not exist in Gen-I do exist in Pokemon Go (e.g. Dark type moves).

So I'm wondering which type chart the game is using for move effectiveness.

1. According to Bulbapedia, in Gen I Bug attacks were super-effective against Poison, but in Gen II-V Bug attacks are not very effective against Poison. What is it in Pokemon Go?
2. Similarly, in Gen II-V Ghost attacks are not very effective against Steel, but in Gen VI Ghost attacks are normal effective against Steel. Does anyone have a Magnemite, is it Steel type? Does it resist Ghost?
3. Does STAB exist in this game?

Comment: It should be 6th gen, if Fairy is present in the game. Just check Jigglypuff's type.

Comment: Bulbapedia notes that the same-type attack bonus has been in the game since Gen I. If it's not currently implemented I expect it will be soon. Does anyone know a good way to test? The display doesn't show the damage dealt for each attack (only a bar graph for each mon's health).

Comment: @pinckerman Confirmed, Jigglypuff is Normal/Fairy. So it's using the Gen 6 moveset and STAB tables?

Answer (score 13):

Through testing on the subreddit [/r/TheSilphRoad](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4t8seh/pokemon_go_type_advantage_chart/), the answers to 1 and 2 are:

- It uses a modified 6th Gen chart as evidenced by the Fairy and Steel types.
- There are no 4x or 0x attacks, so Ground can hit Flying, and Normal can hit Ghost etc.
- Values have been changed:

  - 2x --> 1.25x
  - 1/2x --> 0.85x

As for 3, Same Type Attack Bonus (STAB) has been found in the game files to be 1.25x aswell.

Comment: Great work! Could you elaborate on what things like STAB are, for non-experts?

Comment: @rensa STAB = Same Type Attack Bonus. In the main games when a pokemon uses an attack that is the same type as the pokemon, it gets a 50% damage boost.

Comment: You might want to include that 1/4x attacks also are not implemented.

Answer (score 4):

There is STAB in the game it gives a 25% bonus to an attack. This is especially relevant given the charge meter is filled by 0.5 for each 1 HP of damage dealt.

[source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/180967-pokemon-go/74036311)

[source 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274492/does-pokemon-go-take-into-account-stab-in-gym-battles/275378#275378)

Answer (score 2):

6th Gen, because the Fairy type exists, and Steel isn't resistant to Ghost and Dark type attacks (otherwise it would be overpowered).

I don't know about STAB.