# extra 50% damage for pokemon using attacks with its own type?

Tags: pokemon-go

We know this happens for previous Pokemon games. For example, if I have a fire type pokemon, it deals extra (50%) damage when using fire type attacks. 
So my question is does Pokemon Go also has this setting?

Comment: The proposed duplicate specifically asks if STAB exists, which is the in-game term for what this question asks about.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274492/does-pokemon-go-take-into-account-stab-in-gym-battles this one too