# Do moves or Pokemon types count towards strengths or weaknesses?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am aware than in Pokemon, different types have strengths and weakness to other types.

[image]

But I have noticed that in Pokemon Go, Pokemon can have moves that are not in their type for example this Golbat:

[image]

So does the dark type move count towards the Golbat's strengths/weaknesses or is it the actual poison/flying type of the Pokemon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which generation does Pokemon Go base it's move type effectiveness on?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273484/which-generation-does-pokemon-go-base-its-move-type-effectiveness-on)

Comment: Flagging for mod attention, your profile picture is not appropriate.

Comment: @Alex, what is inappropriate?

Comment: @Timelord64 look at my flag desc. It's not appropriate. Look in the middle circle

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate (of the current duplicate target, anyway). The target question asks Which type effectiveness chart is used. This question asks if the type-effectiveness chart applies to the attack's type, or the pokemon's type. (basically, **"My pokemon is poison/flying, but it has a dark move, what's up?"**)

Answer (score 1):

Pokémon can have moves that don't match their type(s). You gain a [STAB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274492/does-pokemon-go-take-into-account-stab-in-gym-battles) bonus for attacks that match your Pokémon's types, but otherwise it is just the **attack's type** (not your Pokémon's type) against the **defender's type(s)** in the type effectiveness chart.

In your specific case, the Dark type attack an your Poison/Flying Golbat does not receive any bonus damage from Golbat's typing, but a Dark typed move may help it against things like Psychic types which would likely have attacks that do extra damage to Poison types.

Comment: what do you have to go on to say STAB exists? the origi al question asks if STAB is in play, and the current answer is effectively ***no***.

Comment: @Timelord64 There is a link in my answer to another question ["Does Pokemon Go take into account STAB in gym battles?"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274492/does-pokemon-go-take-into-account-stab-in-gym-battles). The answer there draws from the [decoded protobuf file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf). in it you can see **TemplateId: "BATTLE_SETTINGS"** and within that block, the entry: *"SameTypeAttackBonusMultiplier: 1.25"*