# Can a Pokemon learn an attack move that doesn't correspond to its type?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can a Pokemon learn an attack move that doesn't correspond to its type? For example, in the regular games Charizard can learn the move earthquake despite it being a Fire and Flying type Pokemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Pokemon have specific sets of moves that it may come with. A Reddit user [curated a handy guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gAZUFAQQobIsI2wvVzkU_r7XrVwbaQv6cktaWnYzR4Q/edit#gid=0) with almost all known move sets for each Pokemon. Moves cannot otherwise be taught.

Some Pokemon *do* have moves of a different type. For example, Nidorina, a Poison-type Pokemon, can come with Dig, a Ground-type move. Charizard, a Fire/Flying-type Pokemon only has one move set: Wing Attack (Flying) and Fire Blast (Fire).

It is worth noting that these moves [will not benefit from STAB](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274492/does-pokemon-go-take-into-account-stab-in-gym-battles), a bonus that provides 25% increased damage for moves that share the same type as the Pokemon using them.

Comment: [Pokemon Go DB](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/pokemon-go-pokedex.html) also shows the possible moves any given pokemon can learn. Whether or not this list is exhaustive, I don't know. But pokemon can definitely learn off-type moves (My friend has a Snorlax with Zen Headbutt- Psychic).

Comment: @Thebluefish   Thanks for that list it's great. Just to make sure that dig from Nidorina, will it still register as a super effective hit on a fire type Pokemon or any type that's weak to ground?

Comment: @user3308258 yes, effectiveness comes from types of moves, not types of Pokémon. Also, it should be noted that super effectiveness only gives  125% damage, and not very effective does 80% damage. There are no type immunities.

Comment: Thanks everyone there is enough information here to consider this question fully answered