# Are compounding type [dis]advantages implemented?

Tags: pokemon-go

Based on the "super effective" and "not very effective" messages, it's obvious type [dis]advantages are implemented in Pokémon Go. However, I noticed immunities do not seem to be implemented (I hit a Pidgeot with the ground-type move Dig). Since originally posting this question, I've learned that the multipliers are different (1.25/0.8 vs the old 2/0.5), but still don't know about compounding [dis]advantages.

Do type [dis]advantages compound like in other Pokémon games, or is all [dis]advantage equal? E.g., will the damage Golbat (poison/flying) receives from a bug type attack be 0.8x, or will it be 0.64x? And will a Dragonite (dragon/flying) take 1.25x or 1.5625x damage from an ice type attack?

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/274269/153376) claims that compounding [dis]advantages are not implemented, but my personal experience having a Golbat battle a much higher CP Pinsir made it feel as if they were (but that's hardly a confirmation).

Is there any information to indicate how thoroughly type [dis]advantages are implemented, since type immunities indicate this may differ from the games?

Comment: Damage taken x2 and Damage done x0.5 make it look like 1/4 without actually having it this way. You need to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this, I realized that the answer I linked to in my question has since been updated to answer my question as well. I'll echo @Joakim Isoaho's answer here:

> Through testing on the subreddit /r/TheSilphRoad, the answers to 1 and
>   2 are:
>
> - It uses a modified 6th Gen chart as evidenced by the Fairy and Steel
>     types.
> - There are no 4x or 0x attacks, so Ground can hit Flying, and
>     Normal can hit Ghost etc. -Values have been changed: -2x --> 1.25x
>     -1/2x --> 0.85x As for 3, Same Type Attack Bonus (STAB) has been found in the game files to be 1.25x as well.

So, **no**, type [dis]advantages are **not compounded**. An Ice-type attack against a Dragonite (dragon/flying) gets the same bonus that it does against a Fearow (normal/flying).

Comment: so 4x --> 1.25x and 0.25x --> 0.8x?

Comment: @scenia Yes, that is correct.