# Pokemon Go attack bonus for two type pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

Various cases here:

1. Bulbasaur is of type **Grass and Poison**, but **Flying** attack is only Super Effective against Grass type pokemon. What is an attack bonus in this case? 25%? 12.5% (average of two types)?
2. Bulbasaur is of type **Grass and Poison**, but **Ground** attack is Super Effective against Poison type pokemon AND Not Very Effective against Grass type pokemon. What is an attack bonus in this case? 25%? 0% (they cancel-out)?
3. Charizard is of type **Fire and Flying**, but **Rock** attack is both Super Effective against Fire and Flying type pokemon. What is an attack bonus in this case? 25%? 50% (they add up)?

Comment: See [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273484/which-generation-does-pokemon-go-base-its-move-type-effectiveness-on?rq=1) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274692/are-4x-type-disadvantages-implemented?rq=1)

Comment: @Dragonrage I know what happens when the attacked pokemon has a single type, but what happens when it has two types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Pokémon has two types, normally the weaknesses are multiplicative, however Pokémon GO does stuff just a little differently than other Pokémon games. If an attack is normally effective to one of the target Pokémon's types, and super/not very effective against the other, the move will do 1.25x and .85x damage respectively (Note: type immunities are considered not very effective in Pokémon GO). If an attack is super effective against one of the target's types, and not very effective against against the other type, it will do 1x damage (the super effectiveness is countered by the not very effectiveness). If an attack is super/not very effective against both of the targets types, the attack will deal the same amount of damage as if it was only super/not very effective against one of the types (there is no double bonus modifier).

Comment: The weakness in mainline pokemon games are actually *multiplicative*, but that's a minor detail.

Comment: OK. So:
1. Super + Neutral = Super;
2. Super + Not Very = Neutral;
3. Super + Super = Super;

Comment: @Nux yep. And not very + not very = not very

Comment: -1; [Effectiveness does indeed stack multiplicatively.](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wzll7/testing_gym_combat_misconceptions)

Comment: wait a second, I do see answer such as in http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290088 that it will be 0.8 x 0.8 = 0.64, or 1.25 x 1.25 = 1.56

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if a type is strong against both types of a pokemon, the effect is added, although it is not exactly double, in fact it is more than double.

- If a type is strong **against one type** it will do **x1.6** damage
- If a type is strong **against both types** it will do x **2.56** damage

In case you are interested, here you can analyze the Weaknesses & Resistances of a pokemon of two types ([Charizard](https://www.mejoress.com/en/charizard-weakness-pokemon-go/))