# Is STAB halved for dual-type Pokemon? (and also the damage due to type effectiveness)

Tags: pokemon-go

I have seen discussion both ways: for example, for an Exeggutor, it is Grass/Psychic type, so, will the STAB make it 25% more powerful or just 12.5% more powerful, since Solar Beam is a Grass type move but Exeggutor is both Grass and Psychic type?

For example, [Pokemon Go Database would list Exeggutor's Solar Beam as 25% STAB](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/exeggutor.html), when Exeggutor is only half Grass type.  I also have heard that if the Pokemon is dual-type, then the effect is divided by two.

On the other hand, what if it is a Psychic attack done towards this Exeggutor, and it is "not very effective"? Is it not effective just as if the attack is done to a pure Psychic Pokemon (like Hypno), or is it just half not-effective?

(please back up your answer with facts, reference, or experiences).

Comment: I really wonder what the downvote is about. Is it not a valid question? Do you know the answer and it is a too obvious answer? What is it?

Comment: VTLO. STAB bonuses are not quite the same as SE / NVE.

Answer (score 2):

On the page you linked to, Psychic is also a charge move that can be learned by Exeggutor. As it is shown to have a 25% STAB boost, it looks like both primary and secondary types grant a 25% same-type attack bonus to moves that share a type with either of them.

That is, 19.6 * 1.25 (to account for the 25% boost) = 24.5

The listed DPS for Psychic on Exeggutor with STAB is 24.6

Thus, Psychic is given an extra 25% damage with STAB, despite Psychic being Exeggutor's secondary type.

For another source, see [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Same-type_attack_bonus#Pok.C3.A9mon_GO):

> Same-type attack bonus (Japanese: タイプ一致ボーナス coincident type bonus), abbreviated STAB, is **a 50% damage boost of an attack when it is the same type as one of the types of the Pokémon using the attack.**
>
> Pokémon GO keeps the STAB system, **but makes it only a 25% damage boost** when using moves of the same type.

---

For your secondary question at the end, the way type effectiveness towards a dual-type Pokemon works is this:

- If it is super effective against one type but not very effective against the other type, they cancel each other out and do 1.00x damage.
- If it is super effective against one type and regularly effective against the other type, there is a single multiplier and it will do 1.25x damage.
- If it is not very effective against one type and regularly effective against the other type, there is a single multiplier and it will do 0.80x damage.
- If it is super effective against *both* types, then there are two multipliers and the attack will do 1.25*1.25x damage.
- If it is not very effective against *both* types, then there are two multipliers and the attack will do 0.80*0.80x damage.

([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wzll7/testing_gym_combat_misconceptions/))

Comment: but I am saying whether that page is reliable. Is it really 25% when some discussion says it really might be half of that due to dual type?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yes. It is reliable.

Comment: what about the damage taken.  The 0.8 and the 1.25 type effectiveness -- is it halved due to dual type?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 what do you mean? Look at my latest edit. You may have typed that right as I submitted it.

Comment: Psychic type move is not effective against Hypno, with only 0.8 effectiveness, I believe. But what if done to Exeggutor which is half Grass half Psychic? Then is it 0.8 also? Or is it 0.9?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Literally in the answer, look at the third bullet point

Comment: ok, I just saw your update to the answer

Comment: interesting, looking at the last part of the answer, looks like it is "additive", instead of "complementary"... so you would not think of an Exeggutor as half Grass, half Psychic, but think of it as BOTH Grass and Psychic

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Yeah, that's how it worked in the mainline series. Also they're not really referred to as "half" types, they're referred to as dual-types, and "dual" infers that it is "both." Grass is the primary type and Psychic is the secondary type in this instance. Lorewise, it's more grass than psychic, being a literal coconut tree and all, but mechanics-wise, it's equally both.