# Is there a case in Pokemon Go where the attacker and defender has a 1.56x effectiveness vs a 0.64x effectiveness the other way?

Tags: pokemon-go

From the answer in this question, it looks like [type effectiveness for dual-type Pokemons can be "stacked up together"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290088).

So if a Pokemon's attack move type is super effective towards both types of a dual-type Pokemon, then it is 1.25 x 1.25 = 1.56 effectiveness.

The cases of

```
1.56 vs 1, or
1.25 vs 0.8
```

are easier to think of, such as Vaporeon vs Arcanine, or Lapras vs Dragonite, but what about the cases of:

```
1.25 vs 0.64
1.56 vs 0.8, or even
1.56 vs 0.64
```

Do they exist in Pokemon Go?

P.S. I think I see a case with a Bug type Pokemon vs an [Exeggutor](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/exeggutor.html) having `1.56 vs 0.8`. That's because a Bug move is super effective towards both Grass and Psychic type Pokemon, and a Grass move is not very effective towards a Bug Pokemon. So an Exeggutor using a Seed Bomb fighting a Scyther with Bug type moves will be `1.56 vs 0.8`. Unfortunately, Bug type Pokemons tend to not have high HP and CP, and [their charge moves](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/bug-type-moves.html) are not that powerful either. I think the strongest is Bug Buzz which is 22.1 DPS (there is no Bug type charge move that is 30 or above).

Comment: I think this SilphRoad post [Testing Gym Combat Misconceptions](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wzll7/testing_gym_combat_misconceptions/) is the most informative available.

Comment: If you are asking what I think you are, then that would require a move to be dual-type which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I think a move doesn't need to be dual type to do that. It can be just a move that is super effective to both types of the defender, and the defender has a move that is not very effective to both types of the attacker

Comment: Silph Road posts seem to be difficult to search, but [Testing Gym Combat Misconceptions 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/52b453/testing_gym_combat_misconceptions_2/) is a more rigorous analysis.  DPS ratings should be recomputed.

Answer (score 4):

Charizard (and theoretically, Moltres) are Flying and Fire types and thereby command total domination in a fight with Paras or Parasect, whose types are Bug and Grass.

This set of match-ups is the only one where both of a particular Pokemon's *types* are aligned perfectly against its opponent. Movesets, however, only express one type at a time. This leaves us two other pairs:

- Golbat with Wing Attack and Air Cutter vs. Paras/Parasect with Bug Bite or Fury Cutter and X-Scissor;
- Omastar with Rock Throw and either Ancient Power or Rock Slide, vs. Charizard with Ember and Flamethrower or Fireblast. Note that only certain Omastar from prior to the moves update still have Rock Throw, however.

Pairs with less-than-total elemental domination are more common. There are two notable configurations you might want to keep an eye out for:

- Paras or Parasect with two Bug moves versus Exeggcute or Exeggcutor with a Grass-type charge move;
- Magnemite or Magneton with two Electric moves versus Gyrados with up to two Dragon-type moves (which, like a Rock/Rock Omastar, is no longer possible on new specimens)

For reference, the list of double-weaknesses is:

- Bug: Exeggcute, Exeggutor
- Electric: Gyarados
- Fire & Flying: Paras, Parasect
- Water: Rhyhorn, Rhydon, Geodude, Graveller, Golem, Onix
- Grass: Rhyhorn, Rhydon, Geodude, Graveller, Golem, Onix, Omanyte, Omastar, Kabuto, Kabutops
- Ice: Dragonite
- Rock: Butterfree, Scyther, Charizard, Moltres, Arcticuno

The list of double-resistances is:

- Bug: Charizard, Moltres, Zubat, Golbat, Ghastly, Haunter, Gengar
- Fighting: Mr. Mime, Butterfree, Scyther, Zubat, Golbat, Weedle, Kakuna, Beedrill, Venonat, Venomoth
- Flying and Steel (surprising overlap here due to Steel Wing): Magnemite, Magneton
- Grass: Butterfree, Scyther, Dragonite, Charizard, Moltres, Zubat, Golbat, Paras, Parasect, Weedle, Kakuna, Beedrill, Venonat, Venomoth, Bulbasaur, Ivysaur, Venusaur, Oddish, Gloom, Vileplum, Bellsprout, Weepingbell, Vectrebell
- Ground: Butterfree, Scyther, Paras, Parasect
- Ice: Dewgong, Cloyster, Lapras
- Poison: Nidoking, Nidoqueen, Rhyhorn, Rhydon, Geodude, Graveller, Golem, Onix, Ghastly, Haunter, Gengar

Comment: FYI: Now that gen II pokemon are in, this list needs to be updated, but I can't get around to it right this second.