# Does the Pokémon's weight affect the damage for "Low-Kick"?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the main game series, the attack [Low-Kick](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Low_Kick_(move)) is a Fighting-type move that deals additional damage the heavier the opponent is. Pokémon Go uses [Generation VI](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273484/which-generation-does-pokemon-go-base-its-move-type-effectiveness-on) rules for moves and attack types, so Low-Kick's description would be.

> A powerful low kick that makes the target fall over. It inflicts greater damage on heavier targets

In Pokémon Go, the attack does not contain the description pertaining the weight, as listed on [Pokemon Go Database](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/low-kick-move.html)

> A powerful low kick that makes the target fall over.

Now that Tyranitar exists in Pokémon Go, this Pokémon stood no chance against Low-kick in the main game series. The reason due to being a dual-type of Rock/Dark, which makes this a x4 weakness to Fighting while being an extremely heavy Pokémon.

With Low-Kick being the ideal move against Tyranitar in the main game series, does the Pokémon's weight affect the damage dealt in Pokémon Go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the most recent [APK datamine](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ujflu/readable_move_info_from_new_game_master/), Low Kick has a set damage number given and has a defined DPS. Due to this, it seems like Low Kick will *not* take Pokémon weight into account when determining damage:

> 207: LOW_KICK(FIGHTING). Fast. Dmg: 6. CD: 1100ms. DPS: 5.45. NRG: 8. EPS: 7.27. WndSt: 300

I believe the fact that the weight part of the move description was left out also alludes to this being the case. This is not the first time a move with secondary effects in the main series has been missing its effect (moves that always cause a critical hit, moves that raise/lower stats, etc).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there are no secondary effects in Pokemon Go at all.  The closest thing would probably be move speed.